# Match new lines also in parser

Tags: .net, vb.net

how can I match stuff that have new lines like this

```
"start does not work
end"
```

this one works well

> "start this works end"

this is how I call the code

```
Debug.Print(ParseData(RichTextBox1.Text, "start", "end"))
```

this is the function I am using

I am calling this for 20MB to 100MB html files, text files etc.. so .Replace(Enviroment.Newline,"")
will not work

```
Function ParseData(strData As String, sStart As String, sStop As String)
    Dim data As String
    Dim i, j, iCount As Integer
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    lines.AddRange(strData.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    For iCount = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        i = lines(iCount).IndexOf(sStart)
        While i <> -1
            j = lines(iCount).IndexOf(sStop, i + sStart.Length)
            If j <> -1 Then
                If j > i + sStart.Length Then
                    data = lines(iCount).Substring(i + sStart.Length, j - (i + sStart.Length)).Trim
                    Debug.Print(data)
                    i = lines(iCount).IndexOf(sStart, j + sStop.Length)
                Else
                    i = -1 'data not long enough
                End If
            Else
                i = -1 'no "stop"
            End If
        End While
    Next
    Return iCount
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You don't match text in parser, but in scanner.*

You can solve this issue in several ways, but I am unsure what you really want to do it (I mean -- is there more than this example or not).

- you split the text first, so maybe don't split it, and thanks to it matching anything will be easier
- write more general function -- IndexOf, that starts searching in line from given position (column + line), this way you can find "end" in the next line

---

Draft on the fly:

```
public static Tuple<int,int> IndexOf(
  this IEnumerable<string> lines,
  string needle)
{
  foreach (Tuple<string,int> line in lines.ZipWithIndex())
  {
    int idx = line.Item1.IndexOf(needle);
    if (idx!=-1)
      return Tuple.Create(line.Item2,idx);
  }

  return Tuple.Create(-1,-1);
}
```

This works (I guess) assuming you search from the beginning.

Comment: can you show me some sample code to fully understand what you mean

Comment: @XK8ER I updated the answer with a small draft taking second approach. This `IndexOf` returns the line and the column, so it does not matter if the text is spread over several lines. Modify it so it could start from arbitrary position.